# Exiting from both loop and onload (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I have this:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'file:///path/to/file/' + 'test.png';
img.onload = function () {
    // code
    for (var i = 0; i < assets.length; i++) {
        //if certain condition met, exit the loop and onload
    }
}
```

How can I exit loop and onload if certain condition is met? Which command should I use?

Comment: Do you mean like using return? :)

Comment: @AdrianRoman Return doesn't really break out of for loops. It returns something for the function not the for loop.

Comment: Of course it breaks out. The loop is not continued. And it does not have to return something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To exit the entire function you could do return. I like to do return false

```
return false;
```

EDIT: Super basic example:

```
function stuff () {
    // code
    for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        console.log(i);
        if(i ===4)
            return;
    }

}

stuff();
```

prints 0
1
2
3
4

Comment: That doesn't break out of the for loop. That returns something for the function not the for loop. Using break would work to break out of the for loop. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_break.asp

Comment: If you do break it will still execute code after the loop

Comment: True. I missed the part about breaking out of the entire function. To just break out of the for loop use break. Otherwise for breaking out of the entire function use return. :)

Answer (score 4):

Using a [break](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_break.asp) should work to get out of the for loop only.

```
if (CODE GOES HERE) {
    break;
}
```

**EDIT**

To break out of the entire function use return.

```
if (CODE GOES HERE) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @JuanTomas Oh yeah. Didn't notice the part the function. Will make an edit now. Thanks.